# Change picture attachment meta of all occurrences of a picture

Tags: custom-post-types, images, post-meta

I have a custom post type with multiple body copy boxes. I want to achieve the following.

1. Add an image attachment to one body copy box.
2. Add the same image to another body copy box by selecting it from the media library.
3. Change the image meta in one body copy box.
4. The image meta of the image in all other body copy boxes adopt the change I made in 3.

How can I achieve this?
Can I do it with https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/ ?

Comment: If you don't care about the development process and just want the custom results, download advanced custom fields and go to town.

Comment: What would be your advice if I cared about the development process?